# PHP captcha using plain text

Tags: php, captcha

It's my first time posting here as it's also the first time I've decided to build a site from scratch for myself. I'm creating a contact page with a basic captcha script. For reasons you might think are crazy, I want to display the captcha as text. I decided against png as the (anti)aliasing was pretty bad with a transparent background and I don't think my site is going to cause too much unwanted attention yet.

Here is my captcha.php

```
<?php 

session_start();

$characters_on_image = 4;

$possible_letters = '0123456789';

$code = '';

$i = 0;
while ($i < $characters_on_image) { 
$code .= substr($possible_letters, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_letters)-1), 1);
$i++;
}

echo $code;


header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$_SESSION['code'] = $code;
?>
```

The problem I'm having is that if I use `<?php print $_SESSION['code']; ?>` it will print the previous code. My programming is pretty ropey and I was wondering if there is a way to show the current generated code in a `<label>` tag?

Comment: You can't do a header() call after an echo. header() only works BEFORE any output has been performed.

Comment: It's printing the previous code because '$_SESSION['code'] = $code;' needs to be above 'echo $code;' To show current generated code just do <label><? echo $code; ?></label>

Comment: It seems to be working properly, as far as I can tell.

Comment: If your not going to add a working captch, outputting txt is not secure, a scrapper or evil prog only needs to find the string, plus having it so easy might prevoke a script-kiddy from showing you that your form is not secure, prob better to leave it out and have proper sanitization and checks in validity like with the mail addresses then to add more useless code... I use the sum of 2 nums that are words as an image. easily implemented and adds abit of fun to the forms...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also output Unicode characters that look like regular ones (but aren't) and ask users to repeat them. The Cyrillic alphabet has many characters that look familiar to Latin ones, but are encoded differently:

```
А vs A    В vs B    Е vs E    Ѕ vs S    І vs I    К vs K
М vs M    Н vs H    О vs O    Р vs P    Т vs T    Х vs X
```

This would be pretty easy to crack, but easy to implement and easy for users to solve.

(With respect to your code sample: skip the whole session thing and just echo the CAPTCHA from your captcha.php file. Make sure to include a hash of the solution.)

Comment: Hi wander, I chose your advice as it simplifies everything to put everything on one page. I know that it will be easy to crack, but when spam does become a problem, I can always up the security as needed. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of plain text consider using [FIGlet](http://www.figlet.org/examples.html) fonts:

```
Font: big
 __  __             
|  \/  |            
| \  / | ___   ___  
| |\/| |/ _ \ / _ \ 
| |  | | (_) | (_) |
|_|  |_|\___/ \___/
```

Here is a PHP library to do it

http://bolknote.ru/files/figlet/

Unfortunately page is in Russian so [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://bolknote.ru/files/figlet/&act=url) is Google translated one (note that translator has broken layout of code examples so you may need to go back to original for those):